# Which version of Java do I need for this

Tags: java, r, rjdbc

I'm trying to use R and the R package rjdbc to connect to an Oracle database.  Unfortunately, due to my company's strict IT department, every step of the process is kinda complicated, allow me to explain:

- For every bit of software we install, we need to get IT to do it for us, and only certain software versions are approved.  I cant easily update them to newer versions
- Our RStudio is version 1.3.1093
- Our R is 4.1.2
- We'll need to get Java installed, and I was tasked with figuring out which version of Java we should install.  As far as I can tell, the version my company can easily install (without much barking up the food chain) is "Java 8".

So my question is:  To connect to an Oracle database, with those versions of R and R studio, is Java 8 "fine"?  Or will we have compatibility issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel your install and update pain. The [rJava CRAN entry](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rJava/index.html) says:

> SystemRequirements:   Java JDK 1.2 or higher (for JRI/REngine JDK 1.4 or higher), GNU make

So pretty bare minimum version. I can vouch that I've used Java 8 to connect. In the [rJava release notes](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rJava/NEWS), JDK-17 and 12 seem to have caused problems historically.

The detail that has tripped up multiple of my colleagues is that you have to make sure you have the **JDK** installed. At our company only the JRE is installed by default on our laptops and people assume this satisfies the system requirement.